# PHP curly braces replace multiple values

Tags: php

I want to place the value lara certain words in curly brackets. But it gives me $ str as a result. So it shows me the word the same without making any replacement.

I try it like follow:

```
function replace($Str){ 
   preg_match_all('/{(\w+)}/', $Str, $matches);
   $afterStr = $Str;
   foreach ($matches[0] as $index => $var_name) {
     if (isset(${$matches[1][$index]})) {
        $afterStr = str_replace($var_name, ${$matches[1][$index]}, $afterStr); 
     }
   }
     return $afterStr;
}

$value1 = 'Apple';
$value2 = 'Orange';

$text = 'The colors of {value1} and {value2} are different.';

echo replace($text);
```

The result that the above codes give me

**The colors of {value1} and {value2} are different.**

But it should be like this:

**The colors of Apple and Orange are different.**

Can you tell me what I am missing so that I can get the right result?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `$text != $txt` for a start. How is your `replace($Str)` going to read the values of `$value1` and `$value2` when they are neither passed into the function or within the function?

Comment: @Tigger Sorry it is my keyboard mistake, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex has `{` and `}` metacharacters. You can't match them as is. You either escape it with backslash `\` or use `preg_quote()`.

Your code is pretty verbose with loops. You can pass array of values to replace with array of destination values and [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does the job pretty nicely.

```
<?php

function replace($Str,$values = []){ 
   preg_match_all('/\{(\w+)\}/', $Str, $matches);
   return str_replace($matches[0],$values,$Str);
}

$value1 = 'Apple';
$value2 = 'Orange';

$text = 'The colors of {value1} and {value2} are different.';

echo replace($text,[$value1,$value2]);
```

You also missed passing $value1 and $value2 to your function. My advice is to pass them in an array if there are multiple values to replace.

Comment: Hi @nec_dev , thanks for your answer. It is working fine thank you. So the important think in your answer $value1 and $value2 . If the $value1 and $value2 rankings are incorrect, the word output will be different. For example if I wrote `echo replace($text,[$value2,$value1]);` then the result can be *The colors of Orange and Apple are different.*

Comment: @Azzo Glad to help. yes, of course the order is important. If you wish to make it order less, we will have to make use of associative arrays and loops.

Comment: But what kind of deficiency or mistake was there in the code I wrote?

Comment: @Azzo As I explained in my answer, `{` and `}` are special regex characters who have a regex meaning. If you want to match them as a literal string character, you will have to escape it. Also, you didn't pass $value1 and $value2 to your function which you wanted to replace, as in your code, they are global variables.

Comment: @Azzo https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php